# How to reditect sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com:8069/web/login

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, http-redirect

Want to redirect my subdomain from :

```
sub.example.com
```

to

```
sub.example.com:8069/web/login
```

in my webhosting admin it does not let me redirect to specific port (says invalid input)

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share your .htaccess rule file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Would love to but really got no idea where even .htaccess is for subdomain

Comment: i looked up on my FPT and there is no htacess for the subodmain so I guess I need to create one via notepad

Comment: yes please, IMHO it will be better to go through some documentation before starting, you could refer apache documentation, cheers.

Comment: I would assume that you cannot use a custom port with a web hoster. It would mean that you have to manipulate the actual http server configuration and the firewall and intrusion detection systems. And I am pretty sure that your web hoster will not grant you any of that...

Comment: So Is there any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that mod_rewrite is enabled.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com:8069/web/login [R=301]
```

It will redirect everything from sub.domain.com on :80 and :443 to :8069 and /web/login

Comment: I have created a file .htaccess iny my FTP sub foler 

the file looks like this : 

        RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com:8069/web/login [R=301]

**But it does not work**

Maybe it is because the http://sub.domain.com:8069/web/login leads to Odoo on digitalocean?

Do I need to enable mod_rewrite somwhere in digital ocean settings?
Do I need to upload .htaccess somwhere on digital ocean rather than on FTP belonging to domain.com and its subfolder?

Comment: Redirecting from a https URL to a http URL won't work: all standard browsers will always show a massive issue, for very good reasons.

Comment: So Is there any possible solution?